# Normalize a Matrix with constraints on lines and columns

Tags: algorithms, approximation

**Context**

I'm working on load-balancing traffic between client and server nodes.

Assumptions:

- every server has a static weight that represents its computational power: $W^0_i$
- we are able to measure with reliability the latency between a client and a server ($rtt_i(j)$ is the latency to reach server $j$ from client $i$)

Currently, clients reach a servers using a full-meshed round-robin. That means all clients "talk" to all servers with an equal probability: $P(j | client=i) = \frac{1}{|server|}$

$|server|$ is the cardinal of the server set (ie the number of servers).

Representing it as a matrix gives something like this:

```
           server 1  server 2
client 1     W1        W2
client 2     W1        W2
```

**Business need**

Now, I'd like to use the latency measure to adjust those probabilities. So I'd like to re-define that matrix $A$ with the first approximation:

$$A = \left \{ a_{i,j} = \frac{W^0_j}{rtt_i(j)} \right \}$$

*Id est*: all initial static weights are "weighted" by the round trip time.

It has two constraints:

- all clients have the same load, so $$\forall p,q \sum_j a_{p,j} = \sum_j a_{q,j}$$
- all servers are well-sized, so they have to receive the same amount of traffic as before. $$\forall j,k, \frac{\sum_i a_{i,j}}{\sum_i a_{i,k}} = \frac{W^0_j}{W^0_k}$$

An error of a specified precision can be tolerated.

**Effective question**

Applying directly the weighting of the weights ($\frac{W}{rtt}$), the two constraints may not be satisfied.

To achieve that, I guess I'd need to normalize the matrix in some way to verify and satisfy those constraints.

What kind of algorithm (or algorithm-class) would ensure a result (and convergence, if the process is iterative)?

Comment: Check if [matrix scaling](http://simonsfoundation.s3.amazonaws.com/share/Wigdersontalknotes1.pdf) helps.

Comment: What is "$1/|server|$"?  Did you perhaps mean $1/W_j^0$?  What do you mean by convergence?  Are you just asking how to normalize a matrix?

Comment: Oh, sorry. $|server|$ is the cardinal the the server set (ie the number of servers). I'll add it to the body of the question.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking.  First you say you want to define the matrix in a particular way.  OK.  You can do that.  Then you say you want the matrix to satisfy certain constraints.  Well, if you define the matrix that way, either it does satisfy those constraints or it doesn't -- have you checked whether it does?  If it doesn't, it doesn't, and you have  to choose -- either define the matrix that way and violate the constraints;  or find some other way to satisfy the matrix, and don't define it that way.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on, here. At the very least, you need to rescale each row of the matrix so the probabilities sum to 1: if you don't do that, they don't even define a probability distribution. (Perhaps I'm just restating a more specific version of your "all clients have the same load" criterion.)

Comment: Couldn't you replace your normalization objective by that of minimizing a cost function depending on the probability matrix `P(j | client i)`?